Ошибка при отправке запроса на сервер в расширении гугл
manifest.json:
{
"name": "Title",
"description": "Description",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 3,
"icons": {
    "16": "./icons/16.jpg"
},
"action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
},
"permissions": ["scripting", "tabs"],
"host_permissions": ["http://<my_ip_server>/*"],
"background":{}

}


"use strict";

const mainSubmit = document.querySelector("#main__submit");

mainSubmit.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // получаем активную вкладку
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        const tab = tabs[0];

        if (!tab) {
            alert("Нет активных вкладок");
            return;
        }

        const activeTabId = tab.id;
        
        // внедрение кода в текущую web-страницу
        const injectSpec = {
            target: { tabId: activeTabId },
            func  : getInformation // внедрится на страницу в активной вкладке
        };

        chrome.scripting.executeScript(injectSpec);
    });
});





function getInformation() {
    const result = {
        data: "1"
    }

    // обращаемся к серверу для получения ответа
    fetch("http://<my_ip_server>/cats/get_milk/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(result)
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            const { res } = data;

            alert(`Response from server: ${res}`);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(`Произошла ошибка при обращении к серверу: ${error}`);
        });

    return resultQuestion;
}



получаю ошибку:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access a chrome:// URL


Попытка выполнить скрипт на новой (пустой) вкладке?

да, вы правы, запускаю на других страницах и ошибка пропадает
